# npm gives error on ionic start appName and npm install..!

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ubuntu-16.04, user-permissions

Node gives me error when i tried `npm install -g ionic` or `ionic start my app blank` on my ubuntu 16.04.
may be my node and npm is outdated i tried to update but had no luck. Please guide me step by step.

[image: After successfully installing of Node when i tried to install ionic and got this error.]
[image: When i tried to make new app using <code>ionic start meApp blank</code> got this error.]

Comment: Have you tried running the commands with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes and got this. 
saqib@khansahab:~/Desktop$ sudo ionic start myapps blank

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Comment: run the command with super user using `sudo` and update nodejs. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: i tried to update nodejs but had no luck. is there any other procedure to update node??

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed node-legacy and everything was boom... working.

```
$ sudo apt install node-legacy
```

Quoting from debian packages,

> "This package contains a symlink for legacy Node.js code requiring
>   binary to be /usr/bin/node (not /usr/bin/nodejs as provided in
>   Debian)."